# Custom Django email script

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm new to Django so don't be mad if this question might seem stupid.

I would like to add some functionality to my django web page. I need to add script that would send newest feed for subscribed users. Basically I would like to activate script when admin saves new post, but I don't know how modify admin page.

Maybe there is other solutions for this kind of task?

Comment: Based on your description you need to create a custom form and set that form class for the admin then on save of the form send an email.

Comment: you can use signals and  post_save method for cracking this scenario